# Are the covector bases orthogonal to the vector bases in the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a 2d Cartesian vector space where the 2 vector bases are  not orthogonal to each other...

If I construct a pair of covector bases in this space ,are they normal to the vector bases?(their dot products =0 )

Answer (score 1):

If $(e_1,e_2)$ is a basis of the euclidean vector space $V$ with scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ then the first vector $e_1^*$ of the dual basis should be orthogonal to $e_2$. This condition fixes $e_1^*$ up to a multiplicative constant. This constant should then be chosen such that $\langle e_1^*,e_1\rangle=1$. Similarly for $e_2^*$: This vector should be orthogonal to $e_1$ and then be scaled such that $\langle e_2^*,e_2\rangle=1$.

Comment: Thanks,that is more or less what I had worked out.

Comment: Can we also say that ,geometrically  any point that can be defined in terms of linear combinations of the vector bases can also (geometrically) be defined as a linear combination of the covector bases ? So ,starting from the (mutual) origin one can move geometrically to any point by means of either vectors or covectors,

Comment: @geordief: Yes.